# How to serach specific to date range in Splunk - In my case date modifier is not working for the splunk rest API - services/search/jobs/export?

Tags: json, rest, splunk, splunk-query

I've written python code to download data from splunk for the given search and given date range but it seems date range is not working- I can see logs which are outside of the date that I've entered.

Here is my code snippet:

```
def download_binary_file(self, url_path, output_file_path, auth, data):
       self.logger.debug("Entering DatacenterSplunk.download_binary_file() for dc " + self.datacenter)
       print("Writing logs to file: " + output_file_path)
       try:
           s = requests.Session()
           r = s.post(url_path, auth=auth, data=data, stream=True, verify=self.verify_cert)
           r.raise_for_status()
           with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as f:
               for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
                   if chunk:
                       f.write(chunk)
               f.close()
       except Exception as e:
           self.logger.error("Exception encountered in DatacenterSplunk.download_binary_file():" + str(e))
           self._handle_exception(e)
       self.logger.debug("Leaving DatacenterSplunk.download_binary_file() for dc " + self.datacenter)
```

here is the URL and Data that I am passing,

```
URL : https://example-zone-ms.compnay.com:8089/services/search/jobs/export
data= {'search': 'search source=*FOO_access* http_apikey | fields - host,source,sourcetype, splunk_server, _time, index, _serial', 'output_mode': 'csv', 'earliest': '08/22/2019:0:0:0', 'latest': '08/22/2019:23:59:59'}
```

It works fine except, the date range issue, always I am getting last 7 days of log irrespective of the date range I entered. For this range
earliest=08/22/2019:0:0:0 -d latest=08/23/2019:0:0:0
I can getting from Aug 29 - Aug 22

Answer (score 0):

You can include the earliest and latest in the search string, no need to include `-d`

`data= {'search': 'search source=*FOO_access* http_apikey | fields - host,source,sourcetype, splunk_server, _time, index, _serial earliest=08/22/2019:0:0:0 latest=08/23/2019:0:0:0', 'output_mode': 'csv'}`

Alternatively, if you want to pass it as arguments, you can use the following

`data= {'search': 'search source=*FOO_access* http_apikey | fields - host,source,sourcetype, splunk_server, _time, index, _serial" 'earliest_time': "08/22/2019:0:0:0", 'latest_time': "08/23/2019:0:0:0", 'output_mode': 'csv'}`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, But I am not passing as (I tried previously and copied by mistake here) - But I am passing my json data as 
```{'search': 'search source=*FOO_access* http_apikey | fields - host,source,sourcetype, splunk_server, _time, index, _serial', 'output_mode': 'csv', 'earliest': '08/22/2019:0:0:0', 'latest': '08/22/2019:23:59:59'}```

Comment: I've tried your first and second approach but I am not getting any single data

```
Data = {'search': 'search source=*kong_access* http_apikey | fields - host,source,sourcetype, splunk_server, _time, index, _serial earliest=08/22/2019:0:0:0 latest=08/22/2019:23:59:59', 'output_mode': 'csv'}
```
```
data={'search': 'search source=*kong_access* http_apikey | fields - host,source,sourcetype, splunk_server, _time, index, _serial', 'earliest_time': '08/22/2019:0:0:0', 'latest_time': '08/22/2019:23:59:59', 'output_mode': 'csv'}
```